# Angularjs Restful using ngResource not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to expose restful web service using angularjs ngResource using java as my backend  everything seems to be correct but don't know What is wrong with my code 
nothing gets displayed in browser help me with this

```
service.js
 'use strict';
 var employeeServices = angular.module('myApp.services',['ngResource']);

 employeeServices.factory('Employees',['$resource',function ($resource){
    return $resource('my service link', {},{
        query:{method:'GET',isArray:true}
    });
 }]);

 Controller.js
'use strict';
 angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).

 controller('Myctrl1',['$scope','Employees',function ($scope ,Employees){
    $scope.allemployees =  Employees.query();
}]).
    controller('Myctrl2',[function (){

    }]);  

app.js
'use strict';
 angular.module("myApp", [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.controllers',
  'myApp.services'
 ]).
 config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1',{templateUrl:'partials/partials.html',controller:'Myctrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2',{templateUrl:'partials/partials1.html',controller:'Myctrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
 }]);
```

Comment: A little more detail? Did you look in Firebug/Developer/WebInspector? Is it sending out the REST request? What are you seeing?

Comment: FYI, you should also declare that controllers depend upon services `angular.module('myApp.controllers',['myApp.services').controller('MyCtrl1'....`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use service of one module in another module you have to inject it.

```js
service.js
'use strict';
var employeeServices = angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);

employeeServices.factory('Employees', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('my service link', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
    });
}]);

Controller.js
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services']).
controller('Myctrl1', ['$scope', 'Employees', function ($scope, Employees) {
    $scope.allemployees = Employees.query();
}]).
   controller('Myctrl2', [function () {

   }]);

app.js
'use strict';`enter code here`
angular.module("myApp", [
 'ngRoute',
 'myApp.controllers',
 'myApp.services'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', { templateUrl: 'partials/partials.html', controller: 'Myctrl1' });
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', { templateUrl: 'partials/partials1.html', controller: 'Myctrl2' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
}]);
```

try this